# Null Exception when retrieving connectionstring in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="strConDev" connectionString="Data Source=dbSource;Initial     Catalog=CatalogInitial;User Id =DEFAULT; Password=PASSWORD" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to retrieve the connection string in my global.asa in the Application_Start method with the following code:

```
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConDev"];
        string strConn = con.ConnectionString;
```

However, this is always returning a null value to con.  What am I doing wrong here?  This is the syntax I was able to find online.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but you've missed the `providerName`. Edit: It's optional: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htw9h4z3.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the `web.config` is in the root of the website? Can you read other things from the `web.config`? If testing on live server, did you remember to upload the `web.config` into that server?

Comment: I found my mistake.  I was using the web.config in the Views folder instead of the global web.config file to declare my connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax all appears correct.  A couple things you can try:

- Copy/paste the connection name from web.config into your code to ensure the names match correctly.
- Ensure the web.config is correctly formatted.  Open it, give the compiler a few seconds to verify it, then check your error list for any warnings.  i.e. You may have incorrectly typed `<connectionStrings>` or you may not have added elements into the correct sections
- Are you publishing the website or debugging it?  If publishing, ensure you don't have any transformations changing the web.config connection strings - verify this by checking the publish location and opening the web.config there to see if it matches your original.

Comment: I'm just debugging the website locally.  I'm just getting started actually.  The errors check out and I've pasted the connection name.

Comment: Perculiar, as @Shadow Wizard mentioned, perhaps try to add an appSetting to the web.config, and see if you can retrieve that through the respective methods.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the WebConfigurationManager class (from System.Web.Configuration) instead

```
string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConDev"].ConnectionString;
```